# Parsing a multidimensional JsonArray dynamically

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to parse json data from the api. The json data I'm trying to parse can be seen here at 
[image]

i want to show the output in listbox for as below
[image]

here is what im trying to do

```
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsons);

foreach (var abc in json.sfkpi)
{
    Resultclass objs = new Resultclass();

    string months = abc.month;
    if (months == "Jan")
    {

        objs.p1 = (string)json["sfkpi"][0]["optima"][0]["productValue"];
        objs.p2 = (string)json["sfkpi"][0]["optima"][0]["productValue"];
        objs.p3 = (string)json["sfkpi"][0]["optima"][0]["productValue"];

        lstAnnouncement.Items.Add(objs);
    }
}
```

but here it adds the same value for for every month that is first productValue
 so what i am doing wrong how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 elements in `sfkpi`, and you are accessing only one element

```
//look at the index 0
(string)json["sfkpi"][0]
(string)json["sfkpi"][0] 
(string)json["sfkpi"][0]
```

You just have to change the index

```
(string)json["sfkpi"][0]
(string)json["sfkpi"][1] 
(string)json["sfkpi"][2]
```